# Mestre-type algorithm for higher-genus curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algorithms, cryptography

Is there an analogous algorithm for genus $g>2$ curves that, given a complete set of invariants, outputs a curve with those invariants?

(I'm interested in particular in $g=3$.)

Any references would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am no sure if this is what you are looking for: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2AA88DDFA88C9A4!5445&authkey=!ACvBwHBLzy-AEHk&ithint=file%2cpdf If yes, then I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I was looking for, thank you. Do you know of an algorithm for $g=3$ (or higher) hyperelliptic curves, as well?

Comment: There are things, but I don't have them at the tip of my  tongue...

Comment: OK, I added a relevant reference in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is [this paper by Ritzenthaler,](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2AA88DDFA88C9A4!5445&authkey=!ACvBwHBLzy-AEHk&ithint=file%2Cpdf) as in the comment. For the hyperelliptic case, there seems to be

> MR2293798 (2008b:11069) Reviewed 
>   Lercier, Reynald; Lubicz, David
>   A quasi quadratic time algorithm for hyperelliptic curve point counting.          (English summary) 
>   Ramanujan J. 12 (2006), no. 3, 399–423. 11G20 (11S40 14G50)

Comment: The reference you posted for the hyperelliptic case seems to be about a different Mestre algorithm, namely that for point-counting.